# Bash script permission denied

Tags: shell-script, permissions, db2

I'm trying to check all counts for all tables in IBM DB2 using Red Hat Linux. When I try to run this  DB2 SQL Script

```bsh
db2 "SELECT 'SELECT COUNT(*) AS ROW_COUNT FROM '|| tabschema || '.' || tabname || ';' FROM sysibmadm.admintabinfo WHERE tabschema not like 'SYS%' order by tabschema, tabname asc" > script
```

Linux will return

```
bash: script: Permission denied
```

Comment: Does there exist a file  named `script` already?  If so, do you own it (see `ls -l`)

Comment: Do you have write permissions to the directory where you are running the command, as that is where the `script` file will be created?

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to execute the command in a directory in which you do not have write permission. This means that the file `script` can not be created or written to.

You can try to run the command replacing the last part, `> script`, with `> ~/script`, which will write the output to a file in your home directory, where you are more likely to have write permissions.